# Time Series with Monthly/Quarter Day Data

Tags: r, time-series, large-data

I have a .csv file where a large number of measurements were performed 4 times in a single day (at 0300, 0900, 1500, and 2100 hours), once monthly for 12 consecutive months (Jan-Dec). Naturally, I'd like to get a time series to model this year of data, but there are a lot of measurements for each time-day-month (really time-month) combination.

At each time-month, there are 3 discrete, numeric, non-time variables.

- 30 observations for Variable A
- 25 measurements for Variable B
- 45 measurements for Variable C
- Multiple other variables of interest, measured once at each A-B-C-time-month combination

For a total of 33750 measurements per time, giving 135000 observations in a day. For a total of 1620000 observations in the entire year. `(A*B*C*hr*mon = 30*25*45*4*12)`

I was hoping someone could help me set up this code in `R`. I don't think it's as simple as a `ts()` function in `R`, and I wasn't able to find anything super relevant or related to my problem. I'd appreciate some direction and/or help. I'm happy to help clarify any questions, but I can't provide any sample data, for reasons that will remain unsaid, but also because the data is too long to be simplified in any short format.

Essentially what I started with is to do a `group_by(Month,Time,A,B) %>% summarize()` which gets all variance of Group A and B over Time. And I repeat that for B and C, A and C, and individually for A, B, and C. Then I can make a time series for each one of these. Is this approach appropriate for a time series analysis?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "set up this code in `R`"?  We're here to help with statistical questions but that doesn't seem to qualify as one.

Comment: @whuber I'm not certain quite how to manage this data. I'm very new to Time Series Analysis of any form. Essentially I don't know if I need to average out the 33750 time observations or the 135000 daily observations into some summary statistics before, during, or after creating the Time Series.

Comment: That depends on what your analytical objectives are.  We need more information.

Comment: I'd like to be able to infer some information from the 33750 time observations based on where it lies within the time series. Essentially, predicting future values based on the summary statistics that come from the 33750 time observations.